# How do I verify a key pair matches? (node-forge)

Tags: node.js, cryptography, node-forge

I need to make sure a client generated RSA key pair matches before signing it. I can't seem to find any documentation ([npm:node-forge](https://npmjs.com/package/node-forge)) on how to do so. I'm guessing I could sign something with it, and then verify the signature, but that's not efficient. I currently have this:

```js
const Forge = require("node-forge");

try {
    publicKey = Forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(publicKey);
    privateKey = Forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(privateKey);
} catch(err) {
    // ...
}

// ...
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer: I don't need to be sent the public key in the first place. You can build the public key from the private key like this:

```js
// const privateKey = ...;
const publicKey = Forge.pki.setRsaPublicKey(privateKey.n, privateKey.e);
```

More information on this solution can be found here: [Extract public key from private key pem using only nodejs/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31032795/15367667).