# Decrypt pgp message using only public key

Tags: node.js, pgp, openpgp

In the following use case, It shows that using the private key when encrypting a message is optional but when decrypting the message, they make the private key mandatory!
How can I encrypted and decrypt a message using only one key, the public key?

```js
const openpgp = require('openpgp'); // use as CommonJS, AMD, ES6 module or via window.openpgp

(async () => {
    // put keys in backtick (``) to avoid errors caused by spaces or tabs
    const publicKeyArmored = `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
...
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`;
    const privateKeyArmored = `-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
...
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----`; // encrypted private key
    const passphrase = `yourPassphrase`; // what the private key is encrypted with

    const publicKey = await openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKeyArmored });

    const privateKey = await openpgp.decryptKey({
        privateKey: await openpgp.readPrivateKey({ armoredKey: privateKeyArmored }),
        passphrase
    });

    const encrypted = await openpgp.encrypt({
        message: await openpgp.createMessage({ text: 'Hello, World!' }), // input as Message object
        encryptionKeys: publicKey,
        signingKeys: privateKey // optional
    });
    console.log(encrypted); // '-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE ... END PGP MESSAGE-----'

    const message = await openpgp.readMessage({
        armoredMessage: encrypted // parse armored message
    });
    const { data: decrypted, signatures } = await openpgp.decrypt({
        message,
        verificationKeys: publicKey, // optional
        decryptionKeys: privateKey
    });
    console.log(decrypted); // 'Hello, World!'
    // check signature validity (signed messages only)
    try {
        await signatures[0].verified; // throws on invalid signature
        console.log('Signature is valid');
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('Signature could not be verified: ' + e.message);
    }
})();
```

Comment: If you only need one key, then you should use another cipher like AES. However,  if you really need to, then you can derive your public key from your private key.

Comment: To derive a public key in NodeJS, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64492227/13376511).

Comment: Is encrypt/decrypt with a password instead of public/private keys an option? See https://www.npmjs.com/package//openpgp#encrypt-and-decrypt-uint8array-data-with-a-password